# Magento returns bad gateway on international sales

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, payment-gateway

We're currently using Magento 1.7 with Authorize.net as a payment gateway.  US orders work as expected, but any orders outside the US receive a bad gateway error.

Nothing shows up in the Magento logs or reports, and no information is sent to Authorize.net.  The only trace of the failed attempt I find in the system is the item in the customer's shopping cart.

Could this be related to our server certificate, or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: What is the exact message you are getting?